# Editing a combo box in access 2007

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2007

I have a combo box on my form that needs to be editable. It is currently populated by a query that provides a set of values based on the value in another combo box. The "Limit to List" is set to "No". The "Allow Value List Edits" is set to "Yes". Sometimes the user wants the ability to add an item to this box. The value does not need to be stored permanently in the tables.

The question is, is the edit feature disabled because of the kind of query that I have for populating it i.e. dependent on another combo box value? What are the options for enabling the edits?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I should have checked this out properly. I was expecting to see something at the bottom of other values similar to what happens when you have a value list. That doesn't happen.

I was able to type in directly into the Combo box and the value did get added to my table on executing the code to add a record. The "Limit to List" should obviously be set to "No". When that is set to "Yes", you get an error message about selecting only the available values.